# Why does underconstrained type sometimes give runtime error?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following:

```
do putStr ""
   return $ map read ["2"]
```

Run in GHCI, this gives

```
[*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I expected an "ambigious type variable" compilation error, but instead this comes up at runtime. Why?

For comparison, the following three examples do give "ambiguous type variable" errors:

```
map read ["2"]

do putStr ""
   return $ read "2"

do [1]
   return $ map read ["2"]
```

---

By the way, here's the original code where I encountered this.

```
readInts :: String -> IO [Integer]
readInts f = do s <- readFile f
                return $ map read $ splitOneOf " \n" s
```

---

This has been resolved. My original code attempted to read from "" at the end of the list. I received the same exception for a different reason when I investigated in GHCI.

Comment: Windows line endings? (`\r\n`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of GHCi's [extended default rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules). If you put the same code in a file without a signature, you should see the error you expected.

(In this case it's probably picking `()` as the type, which is why you get a parse error.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, that doesn't explain why this occurs in my original code; I've edited my post to contain it.